# Should I use Vrms or peak voltage for this calculation?

Tags: led, ac, datasheet, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I want to calculate the following details from the circuit

- Power consumption of resistor R1 in the circuit
- Suitable power rating to be chosen for R1
- Power consumed by the LED  and verify it is within the safe operating range of the LED.
- Total efficiency of the circuit (assume total power consumed by the LED to be “useful power output.”)

1. Should I use Vrms AC or peak AC voltage for calculations? In India, 230V is the Vrms.
2. The LED's datasheet doesn't say whether the values are peak or Vrms.

Since LEDs are meant to work on DC, I think it should be the peak value.

Am I wrong?

[LED datasheet.](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WP7113SRD-D.pdf)

Comment: For AC power you should generally use RMS values (think about what would be the result of using **peak** voltage, would that be fair? Look up what RMS actually means and is used for). I also suggest to watch BigClive's video about LEDs on 240 V AC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q23uh7AjjXw

Comment: Bimpelrekkie , thankyou for clearing my doubts. sure i will watch the video. :)

Comment: The resistor uses a huge amount of power.'

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware that your resistor will have to be rated for peak mains voltage of \$230\sqrt 2\$? Most are not rated for that voltage and so two or more are connected in series to make up the required resistance.

You should also be aware that this circuit is very inefficient. About 99% of the power will be wasted in the resistor. You need to calculate the power and rate the resistor appropriately.

Finally, the LEDs are at mains potential and present an electric shock hazard. They must be totally enclosed in a suitable housing to prevent access.

---

> Power consumption of resistor R1 in the circuit

\$ P = \frac {V^2} R \$.

> Suitable power rating to be chosen for R1.

\$ P \ge \frac {V^2} R \$.

> Power consumed by the LED and verify it is within the safe operating range of the LED.

Use the LED's current rating rather than power rating. You can then calculate the required resistance from \$ R = \frac V I \$. Remember you don't need to run an LED at 100% of its rated current.

> Total efficiency of the circuit (assume total power consumed by the LED to be “useful power output.”)

About 1%. i.e. Terrible.

You'll drop 2 to 3 V across the LEDs and 227 V across the resistor. \$ Efficiency = \frac {2.5}{230} = 0.011 \$.

> Should I use Vrms AC or peak AC voltage for calculations? In India, 230V is the Vrms.

You can use the V<sub>RMS</sub> value.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct diodes only care about "DC". Well, not DC but instantaneous voltage and peak is the maximum instantaneous voltage (as is every other voltage along the sine curve; the diode affects them all).

To be safe and make no assumptions, take the sine wave (all points) and reduce all values toward 0V (not subtract because an AC wave is both positive and negative) by Vd and work with the nonstandard waveform. This is the longest way though and probably requires a computer.

RMS is only ever good for power, but RMS was made to be equivalent to DC for power so you might subtract RMS from the *constant* voltage drop of the diode **in this case** but the lower Vrms is relative to Vd, the less accurate it will be since since there are times when VAC < Vd so no current flows. This approach is basically a lazy approximation because it ignores the fact that current isn't always flowing through the the constant diode drop which is what is required for true "DC" power calculations.

But 0.7VDC<<230Vrms...under 0.4% so you could also just neglect Vd which is what most would do.

Comment: DKNguyen Thankyou sir for clarifying my doubts :) now i understand the concepts.